# Ошибка в адаптере

Tags: java, android, adapter

В методе `onBindViewHolder` добавляю следующее:

```
viewHolder.date.setText(moviesList.get(i).getTime());
```

Ниже добавил

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView date;
public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        date=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
```

Но при запуске выдаёт ошибку:

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x58318fae

Не совсем понимаю какой id он не находит, в xml? Так он там есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему `.getTime()` возвращает у вас число и, таким образом, вы пытаетесь использовать перегруженную версию метода `TextView#setText(@StringRes int resId)` которая пытаетеся найти в ресурсах строку с переданным ID, которую не находит, о чём и сообщает.

Вам надо использовать перегруженный вариант метода, принимающий строку. Т.е. преобразовать данные в строку. Например так:

```
viewHolder.date.setText(String.valueof(moviesList.get(i).getTime()));
```

Comment: Спасибо, отобразилось, но как то не совсем корректно.
Дело в том что у меня в модели API
time Creation date of the item, in Unix Time. Возможно ли как то преобразовать его в нужный формат? не подскажете?

Comment: @Inkognito, Да, [можно](http://www.seostella.com/ru/article/2012/02/05/formatirovanie-daty-v-java.html).

Comment: @Inkognito, создайте объект Date через конструктор `Date(long unixTimeInMillis)`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб а если мы пытаемся вызвать данный параметр в другой активити то что следует добавить к textView.setText(model.getTime()); ?

Comment: Попробуйте добавить в конце .toString()

Comment: @Inkognito, всёзависит от того что у вас за данные и как вы хотите их отобразить. Если вам нужно просто число в текст перевести используйте `String.valueof()`. Если дату - `new Date(model.getTime())`, Если форматированную дату - отформатируйте её. У вас очень расплывчатый вопрос - можно отвечать в течении часа ез гарантии того, что в ответе будет то, что вам нужно. Попробуйте конкретизироваться вопрос и/или задать новый.

Comment: @post_zeew спасибо, но к сожалению не смог разобраться.